# Replace SQL Cursor with alternative to improve performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to do some processing over the following Customer_Item view

| CustomerId | Amount | ItemId | ItemPrice | IsActiveStore | Priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | 1 | 100 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1000 | 2 | 200 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1000 | 3 | 300 | 0 | 3 |
| 2 | 5000 | 4 | 4000 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 5000 | 5 | 1100 | 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 5000 | 6 | 500 | 1 | 9 |

For each customer, I want to subtract the prices of the related items, that are ordered by priority, from his amount, and update the status for each item accordingly
In case IsActiveStore is false or the amount reaches zero, then skip the item

Notes:

- Priorities are not sequential, just ordered as shown for the second customer
- If the price of any item ordered by priority exceeds the amount of the customer (after subtracting the previous items), then it will be skipped and the processing will continue for the rest of the priorities as shown for the second customer

So the customer table after updating should be as follows

| CustomerId | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 700 |
| 2 | 500 |

And the items table after updating should be as follows

| ItemId | ItemStatus |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | subtracted |
| 2 | subtracted |
| 3 | skipped |
| 4 | subtracted |
| 5 | skipped |
| 6 | subtracted |

Now I'm doing this by looping over the customer with a cursor, and for each customer, I'm using another cursor to loop over the related items, this worked but it takes a long time for large data.

Is there any faster alternative to do the same processing efficiently?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you show us your current attempt that would help us demonstrate a set based method.

Comment: I don't have time to look further, but I would research gaps-and-islands techniques using window functions. Also research cumulative sum using window functions. I think the solution will involve components of both.

Comment: The problem with the cumulative sum is that whether or not an item is skipped is both dependent on and affects the cumulative sum and you can't create self referencing formula like that

Comment: It seems they've since deleted that question then @DaleK . Though I would *hope* they could simplify their attempt to demonstrate their implementation.

Comment: "Now I'm doing this by looping over the customer with a cursor ...".  SQL is a set based languange.  You don't loop through your records.

Comment: @Merna - this is where you come back to us and let us know whether the answer below solved your problem.

Comment: What are the expected results if the price in the first row was `10,000`? Would CustomerId 1's first priority be skipped as over the `1,000` "Amount" and the `1,000` would go forward to be used on the Priority 2 item? Or would processing just stop there and all lower priority items be skipped? As there isn't an example in the data of this

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes the first priority will be skipped, and processing will not stop.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK, I will read about the topics you mentioned, and sorry for the late response

Comment: @ThomA it will take a lot of work to simplify what I actually wrote as it is complex, and I tried before to post it but my question was deleted for that reason, I hope that the example and results desired are clear enough

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by a CTE:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES  (1, 1000, 1, 100, 1, 1)
        ,   (1, 1000, 2, 200, 1, 2)
        ,   (1, 1000, 3, 300, 0, 3)
        ,   (2, 5000, 4, 1000, 1, 1)
        ,   (2, 5000, 5, 4000, 1, 2)
        ,   (2, 5000, 6, 500, 1, 3)
    ) t (CustomerId,Amount,ItemId,ItemPrice,IsActiveStore,Priority)
)
, cte2 AS (
    SELECT  customerid, CASE WHEN amount < itemprice * isActiveStore THEN 0 ELSE amount - itemprice * isActiveStore END AS amount_left, itemId
    ,   1 AS substracted
    ,   priority
    FROM    cte
    WHERE   priority = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  c.customerid, CASE WHEN c2.amount_left < itemprice * isActiveStore THEN 0 ELSE amount_left - itemprice * isActiveStore END AS amount_left, c.itemid
    ,   CASE WHEN c2.amount_left > 0 AND isActiveStore = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ,   c.priority
    FROM    cte c
    INNER JOIN cte2 c2
        ON  c2.customerid = c.customerid
        AND c2.priority = c.priority - 1
    )
SELECT  customerid, min(amount_left) OVER(partition BY customerid), itemid, CASE substracted WHEN 1 THEN 'substracted' ELSE 'skipped' END
FROM    cte2
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Although I'm not sure if it will be faster than a cursor, at least not as long as priority isn't indexed correctly.

The CTE itself is pretty standard, you create an initial amount and then calculate the difference for each row.

Comment: Thanks @siggemannen for the answer, I think you assumed from my question that priority should start from 1 and it is sequential, I will update the question as it can be any number not necessarily sequential but still ordered. Sorry for the late response

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those requirements that is in the annoying category that in principle it would be perfectly possible to do everything with a single scan of the data in order of `CustomerId, Priority` but in practice there is no SQL Syntax to express this (whether or not an item is skipped is both dependent on and affects the cumulative sum and you can't have a cumulative sum expression dependent on itself).

A cursor or similar iterative approach (perhaps in CLR) is quite possibly the best way of doing this kind of recursive cumulative sum calculation.

This is an example of what Itzik Ben Gan called "Progressive ordered calculations" in his [omnibus feature request paper](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/over-clause-and-ordered-calculations-feature-enhancement-requests).

The *.doc only seems available on the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130502130042/http://tsql.solidq.com/OVER_Clause_and_Ordered_Calculations.doc)  (This specific connect request was closed as ["Won't fix"](https://web.archive.org/web/20120808140111/http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/254397/over-clause-enhancement-request-progressive-ordered-calculations)).

It is possible to salvage the recursive CTE approach to deal with non sequential `Priority` using [a similar approach to here](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/03/sql-performance/finding-distinct-values-quickly#row-mode-recursive-common-table-expression) to allow the recursive part to still use an index seek but I extremely doubt that this will be any performance improvement.

```
WITH R AS
(
    -- Anchor
    SELECT CustomerId, ItemId, ItemPrice, Priority, 
           RemainingAmount = IIF(IsActiveStore = 1 AND Amount >= ItemPrice, Amount-ItemPrice, Amount), 
           ItemStatus = IIF(IsActiveStore = 1 AND Amount >= ItemPrice, 'subtracted', 'skipped')
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT *, 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerId ORDER BY Priority)
        FROM CustomerItem
    ) D
    WHERE D.RN = 1
 
    UNION ALL
 
    -- Recursive
    SELECT CustomerId, ItemId, ItemPrice, Priority, 
           RemainingAmount = IIF(IsActiveStore = 1 AND RemainingAmount >= ItemPrice, RemainingAmount-ItemPrice, RemainingAmount), 
           ItemStatus = IIF(IsActiveStore = 1 AND RemainingAmount >= ItemPrice, 'subtracted', 'skipped')
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            C.*,
            R.RemainingAmount,
            R.ItemStatus,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.CustomerId ORDER BY C.Priority)
        FROM R
        JOIN CustomerItem AS C
            ON C.CustomerId = R.CustomerId AND C.Priority > R.Priority
    ) AS Q1
    WHERE
        Q1.rn = 1
)
SELECT
    *
FROM R
ORDER BY CustomerId, Priority
```

**[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f9XcGPGB)**

Comment: Thanks @Martin for the detailed answer, I'll try this recursive solution on the actual data and compare the performance with the cursor to see if there is any improvement or not

Answer (score 0):

I think you should ignore this view that you have. Looks like you need two `UPDATE` statements on the base tables.

The first needs to do a cumulative sum over the `Item` table, setting `subtracted` where the cumulative sum is <= Amount. Note that since you also want to set the `IsActiveStore = 0` rows, you need to add it to the `PARTITION BY` otherwise the sum won't be correct.

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      i.*,
      c.Amount,
      SUM(i.ItemPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY i.CustomerId, i.IsActiveStore
        ORDER BY I.Priority ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CumeSum
    FROM Item i
    JOIN Customer c ON c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
)
UPDATE cte
SET ItemStatus = IIF(IsActiveStore = 0 OR CumeSum > Amount, 'skipped', 'subtracted');
```

Then you simply update the `Customer` table, grouping up all those `Item` rows and subtracting the total.

```sql
UPDATE c
SET Amount -= ISNULL(i.Total, 0)
FROM Customer c
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(i.ItemPrice) AS Total
    FROM Item i
    WHERE c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
      AND i.ItemStatus = 'subtracted'
    GROUP BY
      i.CustomerId
) i;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/sd7zsDrG)

Comment: It doesn't address the issue that rows that are skipped shouldn't contribute to the cumulative sum https://dbfiddle.uk/kuw3YCMp - if a customer's priority 1 item is 10K and they only have 1K then they still might have budget for priority 2

Comment: Hmmm I had assumed the logic would just have been to stop at whatever point is too high in the cumulative sum. The edge cases are not clear in the question. I've fixed the null issue.

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface for the answer, the case  that Martin mentioned is right, I'll update my question to clarify this point

Answer (score 0):

This is also a kind of cursor, since I don't see any other option but to iterate through the items that each customer wants, in order of priority, to detect when it reaches his limit.

It makes use of a temporary table to mark items not selectable during the loop (reusing `isActiveStore`). You'll have to see if there's any improvement in performance, beyond the test data.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#civ') is not null
    drop table #civ

select * into #civ from Customer_Item

-- exclude items with price beyond Amount
update #civ
set isActiveStore = 0
where ItemPrice > Amount

-- updating one record each time
set rowcount 1
declare @rc tinyint = 1
while @rc = 1
begin
    -- disabling item each time it exceeds the Amount
    update citt
    set isActiveStore = 0
    from
    (select isActiveStore
        ,   Amount
        , ( sum(ItemPrice * isActiveStore)
            over (partition by CustomerId
                      order by [Priority] )
          ) as SumPrices
    from #civ) citt
    where SumPrices > Amount

    set @rc = @@ROWCOUNT
end
set rowcount 0

-- Items table to update
select CustomerId, ItemId,
    case isActiveStore
        when 0 then 'Skipped' else 'Subtracted'
    end as NewItemStatus
from #civ

-- Customers table to update
select CustomerID, Amount
    , Amount - max(SumPrices) as NewAmount
from (
select CustomerId
    ,  Amount
    , ( sum(ItemPrice * isActiveStore)
        over (partition by CustomerId
                  order by [Priority] )
      ) as SumPrices
from #civ) citt
group by CustomerId, Amount

drop table #civ
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rsu-8VE9)